# Perona Malik Noise Estimator using Canny

Tags: noise, canny-edge-detector, anisotropic-diffusion

In [Perona and Malik](http://bioen.utah.edu/wiki/images/d/d8/peronamalik90.pdf), they state:

> a histogram of the absolute values of the gradient throughout the
>   image was computed, and `K` was set equal to the `90%` value of its
>   integral

My interpretation of this is to take the 90%ile of the distribution of magnitude of gradients. This interpretation however differs from the implementation [here](https://github.com/CSIM-Toolkits/ITK/blob/d8c89499eedeb228f5b127e11055bc245deb891a/Modules/Features/AutomaticConductanceImageCalculator/itkAutomaticConductanceImageCalculator.hxx#L119-L132) which seems to do a double cumulative sum.